# How to show total count of comments from WP_Comment_Query in the custom Comments view for multi-author WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my WordPress v5.8.1 I have multiple authors, I am building a new comments navigation view for each author.
There are tens of comments for each authors post, but below code I am not able to get the comments count for the respective authors posts:

```
function user_nav_counts($views) {

global $current_user, $wp_query;
unset($views['mine']);
unset($views['approved']);
unset($views['moderated']);
unset($views['spam']);
unset($views['trash']);

$author_ID = $current_user->ID;

$types = array(
    array('status' => 'approved'),
    array('status' => 'moderated'),
    array('status' => 'trash')
);

foreach ($types as $type) {

    $query = array(
        'status' => $type['status'],
        'type' => 'comment',
        'post_author' => $author_ID,
        'post_type' => array('song', 'book'),
        'count' => true,
    );

    $result = new WP_Comment_Query($query);

    if ($type['status'] == 'approved'):
        $class = ($wp_query->query_vars['comment_approved'] == 'approved') ? ' class="current"' : '';
        $views['approved'] = sprintf(__('<a href="/%s"' . $class . '>Approved <span class="count">(<span class="approved-count">%d</span>)</span></a>', 'approved'), ('wp-admin/edit-comments.php?comment_status=approved'), $result->count);

    elseif ($type['status'] == 'moderated'):
        $class = ($wp_query->query_vars['comment_moderated'] == 'moderated') ? ' class="current"' : '';
        $views['moderated'] = sprintf(__('<a href="/%s"' . $class . '>Pending <span class="count">(<span class="moderated-count">%d</span>)</span></a>', 'moderated'), ('wp-admin/edit-comments.php?comment_status=moderated'), $result->count);

    elseif ($type['status'] == 'trash'):
        $class = ($wp_query->query_vars['comment_trash'] == 'trash') ? ' class="current"' : '';
        $views['trash'] = sprintf(__('<a href="/%s"' . $class . '>Trash <span class="count">(<span class="trash-count">%d</span>)</span></a>', 'trash'), ('wp-admin/edit-comments.php?comment_status=trash'), $result->count);
    endif;
}

return $views;
}

if (!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
    add_filter('views_edit-comments', 'user_nav_counts', 10, 1);
}
```

With the above code, I am able to build the new nav but the count (`$result->count`) is always zero.
Even in the `var_dump($result)`, the `public 'found_comments' => int 0` is also zero.

How can I get the count of each authors comments count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the count (`$result->count`) is always zero

[`WP_Comment_Query`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.8.1/src/wp-includes/class-wp-comment-query.php#L17) doesn't have a property named `$count`, and the above call would actually cause PHP to throw a notice saying "*Undefined property: WP_Comment_Query::$count*".

> Even in the `var_dump($result)`, the `public 'found_comments' => int 0` is also zero.

That is because the [`no_found_rows` arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/#parameters) defaults to true, which means `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is disabled by default.

But you should *not* enable it if you set `count` to true.

> How can I get the count of each authors comments count?

Just initialize `WP_Comment_Query` without passing any query args and then use the `query()` method to get the total comments count, like so:

```php
$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$count = $comment_query->query( $query );
```

But if `count` is not set (to true), then you would want to set `no_found_rows` to true **and** `number` to a non-zero integer. Example:

```php
$query = array(
    // ... your args here.
    'count'         => false, // 1. Don't set or set to false
    'no_found_rows' => false, // 2. Set to false (default is true)
    'number'        => 5,     // 3. Set to a non-zero value
);

$comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query( $query );

// total for the current results set, e.g. on page 1
$count = count( $comment_query->comments );
// total for all pages, same as when LIMIT is not set
$total = $comment_query->found_comments;
```

So you would want to use the above if you want to *paginate* the comments, but if you simply want the total comments, then use the `count` arg instead.

**Edit:** However, you could also simply use [`get_comments()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) like so: `$views['approved'] = get_comments( $query );` if you don't need to access anything else in the class instance.

### Note about the `status` arg

`approved` and `moderated` are not valid values for the `status` arg (which references the `comment_approved` column in the comments table), and the default statuses included in WordPress core are (see [`get_comment_count()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_count/)):

| Name | `status` value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pending | `hold` or `0` | Comment is awaiting moderation |
| Approved | `approve` or `1` | Comment is approved |
| Spam | `spam` | Comment is marked as spam |
| Trash | `trash` | Comment is trashed |
| Post Trashed | `post-trashed` | The comment's *post* is trashed |

PS: *`approve` and `hold` are not the actual database value*, but `WP_Comment_Query` accepts those values in place of `1` and `0` respectively.

Comment: Thank you. What happens on changing value from 5 to something else in the query arguments `'number'        => 5`

Comment: The `number` argument controls the number of comments *per page*, and anything greater than `0` will turn on the `LIMIT` clause - `LIMIT $offset, $number` or just `LIMIT $number` depending on your query args - check the [link in my answer](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/#parameters) for other available arguments like `offset`.

Comment: And if all you need is to get the total count, then you could actually simply use `get_comments()` - check the "Edit:" in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your function you can try use something like this:

```
$result = new WP_Comment_Query($query);
....

$views['counts'] = count($result->get_comments());
```

The more details is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/)

Comment: Note that when you instantiate `WP_Comment_Query` with a non-empty query args, the `query()` method will be automatically called which then calls the `get_comments()` which makes a query to the database. And then your code calls that method manually, so it could lead to 2 database queries for the same query args, but even if not, there will be unneccesary re-parsing of that same query args. Also, when the `count` arg is `true`, `get_comments()` will make a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query and therefore return an integer and **not an array**.